# Set duration for a While Loop in JMETER

Tags: jmeter

I am trying to stop the while loop after 45 seconds. This while loop has JDBC request in 5 seconds interval.
I dont want the while loop to run forever.

Right now I am using this condition:

```
${__javaScript("${order_status_cd_1}" != "3" && "${TESTSTART.MS}" < "6",)}
```

But its not working.

Comment: `"${TESTSTART.MS}" < "6"` : this condition was true only once, on January 1, 1970, before 12:00:06 AM. It will never be true again

Answer (score 1):

Simple version of Rohit's answer.

- BeanShell Sampler

```
vars.put("LOOPSTART", System.currentTimeMillis().toString());
```

- While Controller

```
${__javaScript((${__time()} - ${LOOPSTART}) <= 45000 )}
```

Note: ${__time()} can't be used in BeanShell Sampler.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/55275878/12895553

Answer (score 0):

Add a [Beanshell Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_Sampler) to your script before while loop and set `TestStopTime`.
You just have to get teststart time using `TESTSTART.MS` variable and add 45000 milliseconds to it to stop after 45 seconds as shown below.
[image]

You can get current timestamp using $__time() function , you can use this function to compare 
The condition in while loop is `[IF(currentTime<=TeststopTime)]`

```
${__javaScript(( ${__time(,)} <=${TestStopTime}), )}
```

You can see in the results test stopped exactly after 45 seconds (Highlighted in the screenshot)

[image]

For more info on while loop please [read this article](https://www.redline13.com/blog/2018/06/jmeter-while-controller/)

Comment: You can use $__time() in beanshell sampler instead of TESTSTART.MS  so that only while loop runs for 45 seconds

Answer (score -1):

1. Add a [Counter](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Counter) test element under the While Controller and configure it as follows:

   - Increment: `1`
   - Reference Name: anything meaningful, i.e. `counter`
2. Amend your While Controller's condition to look like

   ```
   ${__javaScript("${order_status_cd_1}" != "3" && ${counter} < 8,)}
   ```

   This way your JDBC request will be executed not more than 9 times, given you have 5 seconds duration between the request the total While Controller's duration would be 45 seconds (plus time to run requests themselves)

---

Be aware that:

1. [Starting from JMeter 3.1 it is recommended to switch to JSR223 Test Elements and __groovy() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) for scripting so consider migrating to [__groovy()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy) from __javaScript. The main reason is that [Groovy performance is much better compared to other scripting options](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black).
2. The easier way to set how long JMeter test elements are allowed to run is putting them under a [Runtime Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Runtime_Controller)

Comment: Thank you for suggestions. It worked actually I didnt open one transaction completely so was failing.