# jmeter beanshell call jmeter function

Tags: jmeter, beanshell

I have a HTTP request sampler configured.  In the request body, I call out to a beanshell function I wrote:

```
${__BeanShell(createHeader("GET"\,"Customer"\,"${__UUID}"\,"${__time(yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss)}"))}
```

The function just builds some request strings with the passed-in parameters. I want to remove the jmeter function calls (__UUID and __time), and call them directly from within the beanshell function.  I could not find a way to do that.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Don't inline [JMeter Functions or Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) into scripts, in your case you will have to go for code-based equivalents instead, to wit:

   - `__UUID()` -> `UUID.randomUUID().toString()`
   - `__time()` -> `new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss").format(new Date())`
2. [Since JMeter 3.1 it's recommended to use JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) for scripting, in your case it would be [__groovy() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy). If you want to re-use `createHeader` method - you can put it into a separate .groovy file and define [`groovy.utilities` property](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#groovy) pointing to this file.

   See [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) article for more information on using Groovy scripting in JMeter tests.

Comment: Thanks for the info!

Comment: An odd thing is that in the official doc https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html on JMeter functions and variables there's no clear and thorough list of code-based equivalents of those.
So for example __threadNum() translates to ctx.getThreadNum() . And it's explicitly stated in the reference of the function. But for some others it's hard to find the equivalents right away.